# How to export printable text only(or any other packet property) in wireshark

Tags: sql, oracle, wireshark, packet-capture, tns

Long story short - I'm capturing SQLs from vendor tool to Oracle database by using Wireshark.  It already has decoder for TNS protocol (which is great) and I can access text of SQL by

```
Right Click->Copy->Bytes(Printable Text Only).
```

The problem is that there are tons of packets and doing right-click on each of them could take ages. I was wondering if there any way to export 'Printable Text Only' right from Wireshark. Ideally I want to have a text file with  statements.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with TNS.  but you can do something like this using tshark, for example to look at http requests.

`tshark -T fields -e http.request.uri`

So if you can look at the options in the TNS decoder, you should be able to grab that field and redirect the output to a file.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out field name. However in tshark output it shows as byte stream, not as string. How could I convert it to string? I checked tshark manual but it's not obvious for me.

Comment: hmm, with http you get the text output.  You can try -T text but that is only going to print summaries. I not sure exactly....

Comment: Thanks anyway. Encoding from bytestream to string is different problem and 'tshark -T fields' is exactly what I was after in the first place/

Answer (score 5):

Finally found away to do this. First, use tshark capturing tns packets:

```
tshark -R tcp.port==1521 -T fields -e data.data -d tcp.port==1521,tns > input.txt
```

Then you could use home brew Ruby script below to transform from bytes to text:

```
file = ARGV[0]
print_all = ARGV[1]

File.open(file, "r").each {|line|
  line.gsub(",", ":").split(':').each {|byte|
    chr = Integer('0x' + byte).chr
    print chr if ((' '..'~').include?(chr) or chr == "\n") or (print_all.downcase == 'all' if print_all)
  } if !line.chomp.empty?
}
```

Examples are:

```
encode.rb input.txt > output.txt
```

will export printable text only from input to output

```
encode.rb input.txt  all > output.txt
```

will export all text from input to output

Comment: If you change `File.open(file, "r")` to STDIN you can can redirect stream: `tshark -R tcp.port==1521 -T fields -e data.data -d tcp.port==1521,tns | encode.rb`

Answer (score 3):

An easy way of looking at them all that has worked for me is just `Right Click -> Follow TCP Stream`.

A note: unprintable characters are displayed as `.`s. If there are a bunch of these interspersed between all the text you want to extract (as there was for me), switch it to `ASCII`, save it and open it in your favourite text editor (vim for me), then run a search and replace similar to `/\.//g`.